# DB2 Express-C with PHP on OS X (Mac)

Tags: php, db2

I wanted to create an application that's php based and use IBM DB2 for it's database. However, I am having a hard time installing db2 extension in MAMP so I can run basic commands like db2_connect.

I know how to install the extension php_ibm_db2.dll in windows, but I am new with OS X environment and I have no idea how to make db2 works with php. Can anyone provide a detailed steps for me to follow?

Comment: Did you see this: http://php.net/manual/en/ibm-db2.installation.php?

Comment: Have you installed DB2 Express-C on your Mac? You'll need headers to build the ibm_db2 extension, and I think DB2 Express-C is the main way to get them right now. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014927797

Comment: I already did installed db2 express-C on my mac.

Comment: Did you include the headers (development tools option) while installing DB2?

Comment: Yes I did included the headers.

Comment: @AngocA I managed to install pear, and tried to install db2 using the command sudo pecl install ibm_db2 but an error occured:  Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

ERROR: `phpize' failed